# How should I approach this Conditional Probability Problem?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Can anyone give a hint on how to begin this problem?

Suppose $Y = X^2 + W$ where $W$ is Gaussian $N(0, 1)$ noise. Then derive an
expression for $P(Y\mid X)$.

I know about Bayes' Rule but I'm not sure how that helps me since I would get this

$$P(Y\mid X) = \frac{P(X\mid Y)P(Y)}{P(X)}$$

Comment: Note that X and Y are random variables here, not events, so what is the Bayes rule you recall, supposed to mean?

Comment: So does that turn into something like f(x|y)f(y)/f(x)?

Comment: Possibly, just tell us. What is f(x|y)f(y)/f(x) supposed to be equal to? When? And what happens if X has no PDF? Etc., etc., etc.

Comment: So P(Y|X)=P(Y=y|X=x)=f(y|x)=f(x|y)f(y)/f(x) so long as f(x)>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $Z=c^2+W$ and $W\sim N(0,1)$ what is the distribution of $Z$?

Then the expressions for $\mathsf P(Z\leq z)$, and $f_{Z}(z)$ are....

---

Now if $Y=X^2+W$ and $W\sim N(0,1)$ what is the distribution of $Y\mid X$?

Then the expressions for $\mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X)$, and $f_{Y\mid X}(y)$ are....

Comment: Would I be correct in saying (considering the second case): because W (a normally distributed rv) is being added to X^2, their sum, Y, is also normally distributed (And therefore Y|X would be normally distributed as well) ?

Comment: @Tacitus  Yes, and what would the mean and variance be?

Comment: The mean would be X^2 and the variance would be 1, is that correct?

Comment: @Tacitus Correct.  Then if $Y\mid X \sim \mathcal N(X^2, 1)$ then  you can determine the density function of the normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand this a lot better now.